# Bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

It's possible to prove that $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$ (continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$)  and $\mathbb{R}$ have that same cardinality ('cause of you only have to choose the image for $\mathbb{Q}$).

But what's an explicit bijection?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a nice bijection, but an "explicit" bijection exists by the Cantor-Dedekind-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: I've never heard it referred to as Cantor-Dedekind-Bernstein before.

Comment: Michael your answer is complete but that is not an explicit idea of explicit.

Comment: @CameronBuie Well, I guess it's unusual, but Dedekind essentially gave a proof before Bernstein [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN23569441X&DMDID=DMDLOG_0066&LOGID=LOG_0066&PHYSID=PHYS_0453).

Comment: I have heard referred the theorem by almost any at-least-two-member ordered combination of {Cantor, Bernstein, Schröder}. Now Dedekind comes to the set. :-)

Comment: @user87690: http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der-Bernstein_theorem

Answer (score 4):

Using Schroeder-Bernstein, you have that there are at least $|\mathbb R|$ continuous functions--the constant functions-- and there are at most $|\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}|=|\mathbb R|$ functions; this last is the cardinality of the Real functions defined on the rationals , since not all functions defined on the dense subset of the rationals into the Realsextend (e.g., $f(x)= \frac {1}{(x-\ (2)^{1/2})})$ does not extend) into a continuous function from the Reals to themselves. I think Schroeder-Bernstein has an algorithm for producing a bijection.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Ivan: what part of the post do you refer to?

Comment: O.K, let me see if I can turn this idea into an actual bijection. It may take some time (also got to go work).

Answer (score -1):

Since $\mathcal{C}_0$ contains continuous functions, each function can uniquely express as a Taylor Series which is a polynomial of infinity degrees. You put all the coefficients of this polynomial together with the constant term and you can create an ordered sequence which is unique. eg, for $f(x)=\sin(x)$, you can express as $f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}...=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5...$. Then the sequence you create is $<0,1,0,-\frac16,0,\frac1{120},......>$

Let $\mathcal S$ be the set of all these function, then $\mathcal C_0=\mathcal S\preceq\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}=\mathbb R$. Of course $\mathbb R\preceq \mathcal C_0$ since for each real number, there is a constant function for it. Then by Schroeder Bernstein Thm, $\mathbb R\sim \mathcal C_0$

Comment: That doesn't sound right. How would you express $x\mapsto|x|$ using a Taylor series?

Comment: Nope, continuous doesn't imply differentiable.

Comment: Ops I am sorry that I haven't realize it, my approach is for those differentiable functions....